# Dealing With The Type Blob within Scala's Case Classes

Tags: mysql, scala, anorm

I'm using Scala and Anorm for IO to a MySQL database, and so far whenever I create a table within the database, I do have the equivalent of it as a case class and then use that case class's parameters and an implicit connection to do the usual IO.

SQL:

```
Create Table User (id: Int(20), username: varchar(255), password: varchar(255))
```

Scala:

```
case class User (id: Long, username: String, password: String)
```

**Question**: If I want to add a column in the database of type Blob (e.g., profilePic: Blob), what type I should use within the case class? Or I need to have a different work flow for the file related IO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `Anorm` documentation, BLOB JDBC types can be mapped to either an `Array[Byte]` or an `InputStream`:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Anorm